# Personal Certificate gets delted after logoff

Tags: windows, certificate, smartcard, digital-certificate

I am using Isabel 6 to access my account it requires me to install personal certificate in order to authenticate. This certificate gets deleted every time I log off or reboot. I doesn't show up in windows log. Sometime it randomly disappears. Any suggestion why it is happening?